# How to reorder plotly bar plot xaxis in correct months order per year in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, dplyr, plotly

I am having trouble reording my dataframe by month order so I can plot a seasonality plot correctly in r.

I have tried mutliple approaches to fix it and it does not seem to work. Here is my table which is showing the correct month order per year:

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr", 
"Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", 
"Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2018", 
"2019"), class = "factor"), Item = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Beverage", 
"Food"), class = "factor"), sum_units_sold = c(54488, 65842, 
73503, 82874, 78975, 93826, 75098, 85470, 108831, 133739, 87469, 
96005, 74372, 93526, 85655, 95713, 101783, 117764, 112107, 119282, 
79951, 97568, 87642, 91912, 76637, 88947, 85650, 96090, 105557, 
126821, 116862, 125077, 80087, 91296, 86279, 96559, 29156, 31628, 
114781, 123999, 31582, 32427, 92046, 92895, 28474, 31471), sum_of_sales = c(84115.75, 
90219.05, 127423.85, 116271.75, 126889.55, 129136.55, 129551.2, 
121963, 182407.25, 185782.95, 152122.75, 137368.35, 124589.3, 
130210.6, 148284.65, 137323, 171008.7, 166117.95, 194131.2, 171148, 
135850.35, 137817.45, 151609.75, 131792, 130555.55, 125183.4, 
149413.55, 137055.25, 179726.75, 179377.5, 206204.25, 178044, 
136823.25, 129580.25, 153166.95, 137723.25, 49609.6, 44440.25, 
202933.55, 176673.9, 54555.2, 45730.5, 162333.7, 132356.4, 49633.3, 
44106.5), Products_available_for_sale_by_machine = c(13731, 18588, 
21108, 20900, 13741, 18602, 21566, 21130, 14668, 19982, 22593, 
20501, 14717, 19622, 22548, 20598, 15224, 19986, 23130, 20254, 
15530, 20723, 23557, 20692, 15820, 21085, 23583, 21167, 17669, 
21435, 26348, 21670, 20030, 21576, 26416, 22102, 6956, 7454, 
26657, 22299, 7072, 7256, 25791, 22051, 7189, 7319), sum_of_spoils = c(6617, 
8156, 14364, 7497, 7422, 7288, 14915, 6997, 8854, 7527, 13955, 
4998, 9660, 11205, 13574, 4106, 22536, 15419, 14060, 7520, 11968, 
10748, 14609, 4810, 11545, 8851, 10700, 4126, 18379, 11758, 17260, 
4631, 13737, 9101, 12971, 4686, 4053, 2194, 15454, 6560, 5008, 
1932, 10398, 5267, 4957, 2701), Op_days = c(18, 18, 23, 23, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 20, 20, 19, 19, 19, 19, 24, 24, 24, 24, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 25, 25, 25, 25, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 23, 23, 23, 23, 19, 19), spoils_per_day = c(367.6, 
453.1, 624.5, 326, 371.1, 364.4, 745.8, 349.9, 354.2, 301.1, 
697.8, 249.9, 508.4, 589.7, 714.4, 216.1, 939, 642.5, 585.8, 
313.3, 598.4, 537.4, 730.5, 240.5, 607.6, 465.8, 594.4, 229.2, 
735.2, 470.3, 690.4, 185.2, 723, 479, 682.7, 246.6, 202.7, 109.7, 
772.7, 328, 217.7, 84, 452.1, 229, 260.9, 142.2), sales_per_day = c(4673.1, 
5012.2, 5540.2, 5055.3, 6344.5, 6456.8, 6477.6, 6098.1, 7296.3, 
7431.3, 7606.1, 6868.4, 6557.3, 6853.2, 7804.5, 7227.5, 7125.4, 
6921.6, 8088.8, 7131.2, 6792.5, 6890.9, 7580.5, 6589.6, 6871.3, 
6588.6, 8300.8, 7614.2, 7189.1, 7175.1, 8248.2, 7121.8, 7201.2, 
6820, 8061.4, 7248.6, 2480.5, 2222, 10146.7, 8833.7, 2372, 1988.3, 
7058, 5754.6, 2612.3, 2321.4), products_available_per_day = c(762.833333333333, 
1032.66666666667, 917.739130434783, 908.695652173913, 687.05, 
930.1, 1078.3, 1056.5, 586.72, 799.28, 1129.65, 1025.05, 774.578947368421, 
1032.73684210526, 1186.73684210526, 1084.10526315789, 634.333333333333, 
832.75, 963.75, 843.916666666667, 776.5, 1036.15, 1177.85, 1034.6, 
832.631578947368, 1109.73684210526, 1310.16666666667, 1175.94444444444, 
706.76, 857.4, 1053.92, 866.8, 1054.21052631579, 1135.57894736842, 
1390.31578947368, 1163.26315789474, 347.8, 372.7, 1332.85, 1114.95, 
307.478260869565, 315.478260869565, 1121.34782608696, 958.739130434783, 
378.368421052632, 385.210526315789), units_sold_per_day = c(3027.1, 
3657.9, 3195.8, 3603.2, 3948.8, 4691.3, 3754.9, 4273.5, 4353.2, 
5349.6, 4373.4, 4800.2, 3914.3, 4922.4, 4508.2, 5037.5, 4241, 
4906.8, 4671.1, 4970.1, 3997.6, 4878.4, 4382.1, 4595.6, 4033.5, 
4681.4, 4758.3, 5338.3, 4222.3, 5072.8, 4674.5, 5003.1, 4215.1, 
4805.1, 4541, 5082.1, 1457.8, 1581.4, 5739.1, 6199.9, 1373.1, 
1409.9, 4002, 4038.9, 1498.6, 1656.4), total_items = c(61105, 
73998, 87867, 90371, 86397, 101114, 90013, 92467, 117685, 141266, 
101424, 101003, 84032, 104731, 99229, 99819, 124319, 133183, 
126167, 126802, 91919, 108316, 102251, 96722, 88182, 97798, 96350, 
100216, 123936, 138579, 134122, 129708, 93824, 100397, 99250, 
101245, 33209, 33822, 130235, 130559, 36590, 34359, 102444, 98162, 
33431, 34172), percent_spoiled = c(10.8, 11, 16.3, 8.3, 8.6, 
7.2, 16.6, 7.6, 7.5, 5.3, 13.8, 4.9, 11.5, 10.7, 13.7, 4.1, 18.1, 
11.6, 11.1, 5.9, 13, 9.9, 14.3, 5, 13.1, 9.1, 11.1, 4.1, 14.8, 
8.5, 12.9, 3.6, 14.6, 9.1, 13.1, 4.6, 12.2, 6.5, 11.9, 5, 13.7, 
5.6, 10.1, 5.4, 14.8, 7.9)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e7209b1ef0>, groups = structure(list(
    Month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Apr", 
    "Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", 
    "Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(13:14, 15:16, 29:30, 31:32, 45:46, 5:6, 7:8, 
        1:2, 3:4, 25:26, 27:28, 21:22, 23:24, 9:10, 11:12, 17:18, 
        19:20, 41:42, 43:44, 37:38, 39:40, 33:34, 35:36)), row.names = c(NA, 
-23L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
head(df)

Month Year  Item  sum_units_sold sum_of_sales Products_availa~ sum_of_spoils Op_days spoils_per_day sales_per_day products_availa~ units_sold_per_~
  <fct> <fct> <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Jan   2018  Beve~          54488       84116.            13731          6617      18           368.         4673.             763.            3027.
2 Jan   2018  Food           65842       90219.            18588          8156      18           453.         5012.            1033.            3658.
3 Jan   2019  Beve~          73503      127424.            21108         14364      23           624.         5540.             918.            3196.
4 Jan   2019  Food           82874      116272.            20900          7497      23           326          5055.             909.            3603.
5 Feb   2018  Beve~          78975      126890.            13741          7422      20           371.         6344.             687.            3949.
6 Feb   2018  Food           93826      129137.            18602          7288      20           364.         6457.             930.            4691.
```

However, when I plot via plotly - my xaxis is in the wrong order. Keep in mind I am formatting this table from a global dataframe I formatted. This is my code for my bar plot using plotly:

```
## Plotting ##
f <- list(
  family = "Courier New, monospace",
  size = 20,
  color = "black"
)

x1 <- list(
  title = "Month",
  titlefont = f
)
y1 <- list(
  title = "Total units sold",
  titlefont = f
)


## Year Plot ##
seasonal_plotly1 <- plot_ly(type = 'bar', x = final_sum_units_by_month1$Month, y = final_sum_units_by_month1$units_sold_per_day, color = final_sum_units_by_month1$Year, colors = "Set1",
          text = ~paste("Operating Days: ", final_sum_units_by_month1$Op_days, "Category: ", final_sum_units_by_month1$Item, "Total Sales: ", final_sum_units_by_month1$sum_of_sales, "Total Units Sold: ", final_sum_units_by_month1$sum_units_sold)) %>%
          layout(xaxis = x1, yaxis = y1, paper_bgcolor='white')

seasonal_plotly1
```

When I plot - it has the months all mixed up (Apr, Aug, Dec, Feb, Jan, Jul, etc...). ANY help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to work with? For example, a `dput()` or `reprex`

Comment: @william3031 just added dput output to main question.

Comment: Is it copied in properly? I couldn't get it to load. There is a lot there. Can you do a `dput(head(df, 5))` instead?

Comment: @william3031 halfway through there is a line `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e7209b1ef0>, ` that messes it up. I deleted that line and it worked for me. if you copy and paste the results of `dput` into RStudio and then highlight it and Reformat Code (Shift + CMD + A on a mac), it made it easier to see the problem.

Comment: @Will - thank you. I guess I must have put that month.abb in the wrong place cause I also tried that. Thank you kind sir - it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plotly` orders by factor level, which in the case of your data appears to be alphabetical. You need to recode `final_sum_units_by_month1$Month` so that the factor levels are ordered in the order of the months. You can also use the constant object `month.abb` that is part of R's `base` package while recording the factor levels.

```r
seasonal_plotly1 <-
  plot_ly(
    type = 'bar',
    x = factor(final_sum_units_by_month1$Month, levels = month.abb),
    y = final_sum_units_by_month1$units_sold_per_day,
    color = final_sum_units_by_month1$Year,
    colors = "Set1",
    text = ~ paste(
      "Operating Days: ",
      final_sum_units_by_month1$Op_days,
      "Category: ",
      final_sum_units_by_month1$Item,
      "Total Sales: ",
      final_sum_units_by_month1$sum_of_sales,
      "Total Units Sold: ",
      final_sum_units_by_month1$sum_units_sold
    )
  ) %>%
  layout(xaxis = x1,
         yaxis = y1,
         paper_bgcolor = 'white')

seasonal_plotly1
```